# Python window application

Tags: python, window

I just have general question. I need to start with project where will be placed some real time graphs, graphics etc. What should I use? I heard about pyqt and tkinter only. It will be large project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [wxPython](https://wxpython.org/) because of [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/). `wxGlade` is a fantastic GUI builder for `wxPython`. It's not difficult to use and has *a lot* of [documentation](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) and [guides](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/docs/tutorial.html). I've never had any problems with Python v3.2+.

Combine `wxPython` with [`PyPlot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) to create a plethora of graphs. [Here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/27/wxpython-pyplot-graphs-with-python/) is one of many tutorials.

[image: wxPython with PyPlot]

You also can use [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), another popular graphing/drawing library.

#### Example with matplotlib

```
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wx import NavigationToolbar2Wx
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import wx

class CanvasPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

    def draw(self):
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2 * pi * t)
        self.axes.plot(t, s)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    fr = wx.Frame(None, title='test')
    panel = CanvasPanel(fr)
    panel.draw()
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: The main assumption is modern look. Examples from wxGlade looks like win98 style. As I said it will be large project with many options, buttons, real-time graphs. 
-> OR ->
It  is possible to create custom looks in wxGlade?

Comment: `wxPython` wraps native designer elements—so if you run it on Windows 10, it will look like Windows 10, Mac OS X, etc. It looks low-grade Windows 98 style because of `wxGlade`. Do some research on your own on how to custom draw elements, animations, etc. It's just a little geometry and fun. :) @forqed